# Multiple WHEN conditions for the same THEN block

Tags: plsql

I want to use the pl/sql case when statement like in java or c++.
I should combine multiple when conditions for the same then block.

Example:

```
case
  when l_var = 1 then
  when l_var2 = 2 then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('true');
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('false');
end case;
```

I know that I could use AND or OR in the when conditions but this is ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugliness is in the eye of the beholder.  I just look at that syntax and think, "there's some code missing".

I really don't know what you're expecting.  The [PL/SQL CASE() syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/case_statement.htm#i36967) doesn't work the way you would like.  So your choices are to use explicit BOOLEAN logic, deploy nested conditions or choose a different programming language..

Answer (score -2):

reuse the same code or use goto statement http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: Last I heard GOTO was still considered harmful.

Comment: -1. This is PL/SQL, not PHP. The other part of the answer makes no sense either.

Comment: I agree that GOTO is not the proper way to handle this situation. The correct URL if you want to read up on it though is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm#815